# What should I pass as parameter to a method expecting a NSError**?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nserror

I have been creating a peer to peer connection for a new game, that does not use the peer picker. I am however dumbstruck as what to put in here:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID {
    NSLog(@"I GOTS A CONNECTION REQUEST");
    if(connected == YES) {
        //deny all requests
    }
    else if(connected == NO) {
        [session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:???];
    }
}
```

What should I put where the question marks are? The documentation says NSError **.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pointer to an NSError*, so :

```
NSError* error=nil;
[session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error];
```

Comment: That got rid of an error. What should i really put in there though, if i want to construct an error to come up.

Comment: Sadly, UIKit is missing AppKit's presentError: methods, so you're stuck with presenting the error yourself.

The quick & easy way to do so is with a UIAlertView - it's up to you to come up with the title & message, though you could use -[NSError localizedDescription]

Comment: `-acceptConnectionFromPeer: error:` assigns an autoreleased `NSError` to the pointer. You can check if there was an error with `if (error) { printf("ERROR"); }`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error set `error` to nil.

`error` is a means of conveying to the rest of your application *why* the connection is **not** beeing established.

In you example roll your own NSError stating that your application is not accepting connections because it is already connected to a client.

See the iPhone Dev Center documentation for [NSError](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/localizedDescription) to see how to populate it.

Comment: You can't return `nil` (or anything, really) from a method of return type `void`.